# Can someone explain: strstr "\`cat /proc/cmdline\`" rd.live.image does?

Tags: bash, fedora, kickstart

Full line of code context:

```
if ! strstr "\`cat /proc/cmdline\`" rd.live.image || [ "\$1" != "start" ]; then
     exit 0
fi
```

[strstr](https://www.shellscript.sh/tips/strstr/) is defined as:

```
strstr() {
  [ "${1#*$2*}" = "$1" ] && return 1
  return 0
}
```

Additional info:
Code comes from [fedora-live-base.ks](https://github.com/kororaproject/kp-config/blob/master/kickstart.d/fedora-live-base.ks). A base kickstarter file provided by Fedora. I'm trying to understand most of what the ks file does. I'm struggling with a lot of the script part of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strstr() {
  [ "${1#*$2*}" = "$1" ] && return 1
  return 0
}
```

---

```
command1 && command2
```

this will execute `command1` ( `[ "${1#*$2*}" = "$1" ]` ) no matter what, and then, **only if** `command1` returned `0` ( [`&&`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html) ) will execute `command2` ( `return 1` ).

When a `return n` its executed inside a function, it'll stop the function execution at that point, returning `n`

So `strstr` will return `1` if `[ "${1#*$2*}" = "$1" ]` returned `0`, or `0` otherwise.

`[` is a synonym for the "test" builtin.

`[ str1 = str2 ]` will return `0` if the strings are equal.

`$1` it's the first argument passed to `strstr`, `$2` is the second, and `"${1#*$2*}"` is a [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) of `$1`:

> **${parameter#word}** If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the
>   expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the
>   ‘#’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘##’ case) deleted.

Hence, this will be expanded to `$1`, with the shortest match of `*$2*` (< this is [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) ) at the beginning, removed. Then, that expanded value will be compared against the full `$1` (**This is just a *fancy* way to check if `$1` contains `$2`**).

Ok, now, what are `$1` and `$2`?

`$2` is simply `rd.live.image`, and

`$1` is the contents of the file `/proc/cmdline`

> [`/proc/cmdline`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-proc-cmdline): This file shows the parameters passed to the
>   kernel at the time it is started.

then, finally:

> What strstr “`cat /proc/cmdline`” rd.live.image does?

Is checking if `rd.live.image` is in the parameters passed to the kernel at the time it is started. In that case, it'll return `0`, otherwise, it'll return `1`.

Comment: In addition to this, the backticks and `$` are escaped at the calling site because these lines are actually being written to another file, and are not directly run by the kickstart file.

Comment: Thank yall both. @muru is there a way I can find which file the lines are being written to?

Comment: @AliMAhmed see this line: https://github.com/kororaproject/kp-config/blob/master/kickstart.d/fedora-live-base.ks#L68